# How to return a 404 error from OData Producer?

Tags: http, odata, odata4j

I have an OData Producer (using odata4j Java).
In the getEntities() method I check that the entity name supplied exists in the meta-data document.
If the name is not present I want to return a http 404 error - Not Found.

How do I return this error when the producer is due to return a EntitiesResponse object?
What's the way of building/returning errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (as of version 0.5), you can throw [NotFoundException](http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/source/browse/odata4j-core/src/main/java/org/odata4j/producer/exceptions/NotFoundException.java).

Hope that helps,

- john